# Delete with custom primary key

Tags: laravel-8

On my project I used custom primary key `product_id` instead of `id`

```
<td>
    <form action="/admin/product/{{ $row_product->product_id }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('delete')
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{{ route('edit_product',$row_product->product_id) }}">Edit</a>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary ms-0" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?')">Delete</button><br>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-2" href="{{ route('product_variant_list', ['product_id' => $row_product->product_id] ) }}">Product Variants</a>
    </form>
</td>
```

In model(Product) I have set

```
protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
```

Route is

```
Route::delete('/admin/product/{product}',[ProductController::class, 'destroy'])
                ->middleware('admin');
```

Now in ProductController I used this aproach:

```
public function destroy(Product $product_id)
    {
        $product_id->delete();
    }
```

On the other pages where primary key is `id` it works but here is not working with custom primary key, is there a way to make it work ?
I found a method to work but I would like to make the same thing on the website and also I would like to know how to make it works with custom primary key
The method I use to delete for the moment is :

```
public function destroy($product_id)
    {
        $product = Product::where('product_id', '=', $product_id);
        $product->delete();
    }
```

On image to delete I am useing the same thing but I get a different result [image: image delete]

```
public function destroy(Product_image $image)
{
    $image->delete();
}
```

And this is what I get on product when I try to delete
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`$product_id` is NOT your product's id in you first `destroy` method. It's a instance of Product which needs the id to be added if you want to edit/delete an existing model.

From your route, your product's id is passed through the `{product}` parameter, so this should work:

```
public function destroy(Product $product_id, int $product)
{
    $product_id->find($product)->delete();
}
```

Note 1: Your `$primaryKey` has no relevance at all in the process. Your model will handle the process properly since you already expecified which field to be used as primary for all means.

Note 2: Check your `edit` and `update` methods. In those you must be having the same issue (or the solution already implemented) if you're also injecting `Product` as dependency.

Comment: Ok so why do on the other tables I can do it like that but on product I can't I am very confused about it, added some pictures so you can see what I get with die and dump

Comment: As said before, ```$image``` is just an instance of ```Product_image``` with NO ```id```. Don't confuse the dependency injection with the parameter you're getting from the route. When you inject a dependency you're just creating an object with default values for parameters. You need to query the exact model you want to edit/delete (Ex. ```$image->find($parameter)```) for the instance to refer to it. You can't delete an instance with no id. Then, ```$parameter``` is the value you're getting from your route (whichever is the name of the ```{parameter}``` your passing from your route).